Can the little horn of Daniel 7 be Hadrian?
Could the little horn of the fourth beast in Daniel 7 be Hadrian who built a pagan temple above the ruined temple site which might be considered an abomination?

@ Sean - This prophecy question deals with the "little horn" in the main, so it seemed to be more appropriate to use this new tag., instead of "son of man". If you disagree feel free to roll it back. Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!

Was the "Little Horn" Hadrian (76-138 A.D.)?Four BeastsMost reputable Hebrew scholars identify the four beasts as (1) Babylon, (2) Persia, (3) Greece, and (4) Roman empires. So the person in question, "another little horn", comes from the Roman Empire.
And by way of anticipation, The Little Horn, appears during the era when The Kingdom of God begins to spread throughout the world. (7:13-14), and when the "people of the saints of the Most High" possess this Kingdom. (7:27).
So how does this all fit in the Roman Empire? The history of Rome shows that there were ten rulers (horns) during the end of the Republic of Italy through the Emperors of Rome unto the Fall of Jerusalem! [Note that the prophecy did not require them all to be called "Caesar", just rulers (horns).] (1) Sulla, (2) Julius Caesar, (3) Augustus, (4) Tiberius, (5) Caligula, (6) Claudius, (7) Nero, (8-10) Galba, Otho, Vitellus --->Vespasian!
The Little HornAfter Nero's suicide, there arose three emperors (horns) in rapid succession (one year) who were all killed. Then Vespasian took over and became the Emperor. Vespasian is the little horn. It was he who was sent to Palestine to "make war on the Jews." (7:21) And this war was to last for Time, times, and half a time, that is, 3 1/2 years. This was the exact period of time that Judea was attacked, ending with the Destruction of the Temple. (67-70 A.D.)
Notice it was prophesied that this emperor would "be diverse" (v. 24) and that  "his look was more stout than his fellows." (v. 20) History tells us that Vespasian was NOT of the Julian line of emperors, but began the different  Flavian line. And that in appearance he, who had worked his way up the military, was a man with a thick, stout neck in appearance---unlike the earlier emperors who were more normal.
Kingdom of GodIt was the Destruction of Jerusalem and the Temple by this horn that paved the way for the new Kingdom of God to begin its spread throughout the world without the encumbrance of the Jewish religion standing in its way. It was time for the saints to possess the Kingdom. (7:27) Remember that Jesus had begun His ministry declaring that the Kingdom was at hand. Notice the announcement of Jesus at the Last Supper:

I appoint unto you a kingdom, as my Father hath appointed unto Me. That ye may eat and drink in my Kingdom, and sit on thrones judging the twelve tribes of Israel. (Luke 22:29-30)

So it was not Hadrian, but Vespasian who was described in Daniel 7 as the little horn.

Answer
It is possible to interpret anything from the Scripture and make our own stories or theories. But these will not amount to truth. To see the truth, all the parts (jigsaw pieces) should be accounted and logically sequenced to get the whole picture.
Explanation
So, the little horn of Daniel 7 can be interpreted to be Hadrian but this is far from the truth!
Let me examine all the points regarding this little horn of Daniel 7 (In fact, everything is interpreted already by an angel, most probably Gabriel (Dan 8:16), for us – Dan 7:16):

The fourth Beast is the fourth “kingdom” (empire) on the earth, which is “different” and quite powerful (hence unnamed!) unlike the earlier ones (Dan 7:23). This is the Roman Empire.

The ten horns are ten kings/kingdoms that “shall rise” “out of this kingdom” (verse 24). So, clearly, these ten kings are not the original Roman Empire but will arise out of the original Roman Empire later. In other words, the original Roman Empire will continue through these ten kings/kingdoms.

The little horn is “another” horn that came up “among” (Dan 7:8) and “after” (Dan 7:24) the first ten. The little horn is different from the ten horns (verse 24). Its “appearance was greater than” the ten (verse 20). In fact, it uprooted three kings/kingdoms from the ten (verse 8).


[In fact, in verse 20, it is written “its appearance was greater than” the ten. The Aramaic word for “appearance” is “chezev” and is used 12 times in the entire Scripture. In all the other 11 times it is translated as “visions”!! So the correct translation would be: “its vision was greater than” that of the ten!  Again, the Aramaic word for “greater” is “rab” which is usually translated as “great”. But it is also translated as “lord” (Dan 2:10), “captain” (Dan 2:14), “chief” (Dan 2:48) and “master” (Dan 4:9). So, the little horn was the leader/captain/lord/master of the remaining 7 horns (3 were uprooted by it) with a great vision]

This little horn is full of blasphemies (Dan 7:25) against the Most High.

It “made war” with the saints of God and “overcame” them for 1260 long years (Dan 7:21 and 25).

It will try to change the calendar and laws of God (verse 25).

The little horn was to rise from “among” the original Roman Empire but at a later stage (“after”) in history and is to continue until the second coming of Lord Jesus Christ (Dan 7:27).


Conclusion
Since Hadrian never continued until the second coming of Jesus, the little horn cannot be Hadrian! Also Hadrian never fulfilled any of the above seven points.
